# Props not passing down to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm making the `reactjs` todo app.
In the components folder, I have 2 files TodoList.js and TodoDetails.js.

In TodoLis.js, I have item as a prop ()
to pass down to TodoDetails.js.
However, I get an error as the item is undefined(item in li and div tags) in TodoDetails.js.
How can I fix the issue and render lists of todos(which is hardcoded for now)?

I've added TodoContexts.js.
TodoContextProvider is in App.js.

TodoList.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import TodoDetails from './TodoDetails';
import { TodoContext } from '../contexts/TodoContexts';

const TodoList = () => {
  const { items } = useContext(TodoContext);
  return items.length ? (
    <div className="todo-list">
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => {
          return ( <TodoDetails item={item} key={item.id} /> )
          console.log(item, "item");
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="empty">
      You have no todos at the moment.
    </div>
  )
}

export default TodoList
```

TodoDetails.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { TodoContext } from '../contexts/TodoContexts';

const TodoDetails = ({ item }) => { //TodoList item is props
  const { removeItems } = useContext(TodoContext);

  return (
    <li onClick={() => removeItems(item.id)}>
      <div className="items">{item.items}</div>
      <div className="date">{item.date}</div>
    </li>
  )
}

export default TodoDetails
```

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'; //npm install uuid

export const TodoContext = createContext();

const TodoContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {items: 'laundry', date: '2020-11-18', id: 1},
    {items: 'lunch', date: '2020-11-20', id: 2},
  ]);

  const addItems = (items, date) => {
    setItems([...items, {items, date, id: uuidv4()}]);
  };

  const removeItems = (id) => {
    setItems(items.filter(item => item.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={{ items, addItems, removeItems }}>
      {props.children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default TodoContextProvider
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Form from './components/Form';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import TodoContextProvider from './contexts/TodoContexts';
import TodoDetails from './components/TodoDetails';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TodoContextProvider>
        <Navbar />
        <Form />
        <TodoList />
        <TodoDetails />
      </TodoContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of TodoContexts.js?

Comment: @Matt I think first is to  see the provider to see if he do something wrong.

Comment: Ive added TodoContexts.js.

Comment: Thanks and do you have `TodoContextProvider` above `TodoList` in the tree?

Comment: I have TodoContextProvider  in App.js. Ive added App.js code above. and thank you so much Matt.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the createContext not initialize correctly you need to do the following:

```
 createContext({
  items: [],
  addItems: () => {},
removeItems:() => {}
})
```

like that you structure your context